# How to refresh view during working process

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, polling

I would like to ask about help with my 'refresh view' problem ;)

I have an application which check some data in database. Whole process takes a long time f.e an hour so I would like to inform the user what is happening in specific moment (f.e element 1 checked, element 2 checked and so on..). My problem is how to do it when 'checking process' is working in bean.

I have one template with dialog and the command button calls it on start and hide when the method will finish. This works fine, but the problem occurs when I wanted to put sth like log info to this dialog.

Code:

1. Template

   ```
   <h:body styleClass="workBody" onload="logToggle();">
   <h:form id="form">
       <p:ajaxStatus onstart="dialog.show();" onsuccess="dialog.hide();"/>
       <p:poll interval="2" update="logScroll"  global="false"/>
       <p:dialog id="dialog" header="LOADING.."  widgetVar="dialog" resizable="false"
                 width="400" modal="true" showEffect="clip" closable="false"
                 hideEffect="fold">
           <br />
           <p:scrollPanel style="height:300px"  id="logScroll" mode="native">
               <p:dataTable id="logPanel" var="log" value="#{viewBean.log}">
               <p:column  headerText="Log">
                   <h:outputText value="#{log}" />
               </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
           </p:scrollPanel>
           <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
       </p:dialog>

       <p:layout fullPage="true"  id ="layout">
           <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="center">
               <ui:insert name="center"></ui:insert>
           </p:layoutUnit>
       </p:layout>
   </h:form>
   ```
2. UIInsert

   ```
   <ui:define name="center">
       <p:panel >
           <p:commandButton value="Check" action="#{actionClass.checkProject}" />         
       </p:panel>
   </ui:define>
   ```
3. ActionClass

   ```
   public class AccionClass {
       static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(actionBean.class);
       private ArrayList<String> log;

       public ArrayList<String> getLog() {
           return log;
       }

       public void setLog(ArrayList<String> log) {
           this.log = log;
       }

       public void checkProject() {
           try {
               logger.info("Project Checking : started");
               for (String sequence : selectedNodes) {
                   logger.info("Project Checking : node " + sourceNode.getName());
                   LinkedHashMap<String, Item> nodeElements = getNodeItems(sequence)
                   for (WsItem item : nodeElements.values()) {
                       checkItem(item);
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               logger.info("Check project exception", ex);
           }
       }

       public void checkItem(Item item) {
           logger.info("Checking item : started");
           try {
               Item itemToClone = sourceInstance.getApi().getVersionItem(version);
               logger.info("Checking item : item " + itemToClone.getName() + " with version " + version);
               log("info", "Checking item : item " + itemToClone.getName() + " with version " + version, false);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               messages.put("error in check item with version " + version, "Error");
               logger.info("error in check item with version " + version);
           }
       }

       public void log(String severity, String message, Boolean isMessage) {
           log.add(message);
       }
   }
   ```
4. ViewBean

   ```
   @SessionScoped
   @ManagedBean
   public class ViewBean {

       private ArrayList<String> log;
       static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ViewBean.class);
       public ActionClass action = new ActionClass();

       public ArrayList<String> getLog() {
           if (page.equals("checkProject")) {
               return action.getLog();
           } else return log;
       }

       public void setLog(ArrayList<String> log) {
           this.log = log;
       }
   }
   ```

My idea was that after checkProject call, the process will be working (for loops in actionClass) and ajax poll will refresh dialog with datatable using viewBean getLog. 
 
At this moment data flow looks like:

1. getLog from viewBean is calling every 2 sec. before i click commandButton.
2. after commandButton click dialogbox is showed and get Log with no values is got - datatable is empty.
3. checkProject is working, things are written to log4j logger and actionClass log but viewBean.getLog is not calling.
4. after method finish view is refreshed and dialog is closed.

When I didn't clear the log in actionClass and did this method again, in 2nd step I got the values from last call, so method works.

Thanks for help..

Comment: The problem is that your action method execute the process sequentially with the request/response. To solve your problem, you must seek for a parallel process (I don't recommend starting a `Thread` nor a `Runnable` in web applications).

Comment: Is there any method to refresh View from Bean f.e using request context or some java script ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [p:poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) is exactly what your looking for.

---

Comment: I have the p:poll in template and I tried inside dialog and outside and nothing works..

Comment: I think yes, but when process is in loop in backing bean poll doesn't work..it works when view get response from bean (after action)

Comment: I dont know the internals of ajax but i guees that there can only be one request at a time. Generally its not a good idea to have actiona running so long. What happens if the user quites etc. ? I would rather shedule the action and keep track of its process. This might be a bit more complex to implement but is alot more cleaner, gives you more controll and is more transparent.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP: the polls get their response only when the view gets a response from the bean. I would be interested in any help on this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem and my implementation methods are in this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070165/watching-traffic-in-the-backing-bean-in-pdialog). I'm interresting in any helps.