# Watching traffic in the backing bean in p:dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a method A() that it executed on Button clicked. This is hapened on backingBean (Onserver) and on View(ClientSide) i have a p:dialog  displayed.
Method A() contain a for loop then in every  cycle of this loop i would know the step who this loop is in?

BackingBean Code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "generationBean")
 @SessionScoped
public class GenerationBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{appBean}")
private AppBean applicationBean;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{login}")
private Login loginB;
@EJB
private UserFacadeLocal userFacade;
@EJB
private GeneralSettingsFacadeLocal generalSettingFacade;
@EJB
private GenerationHistoryFacadeLocal generationHistoryFacade;
@EJB
private GenerationSiteFacadeLocal generationSiteFacade;
@EJB
private HistorySiteGenerationFacadeLocal historySiteGenerationFacade;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedRegion = "choix";
    setLabelBoutonGen("Générer");
    loadDirectoryRegion();
    generatedSites = new ArrayList();

}
 public void genererDPT() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {

    generatedSites = new ArrayList();

    String formatTime = "H_mm_ss"; 
    for (Iterator it = sitesDest.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

                    String obj = it.next().toString();
                    currentSite = obj;
                    if (selectedTypeOt.equals("OT IUB enchaîné (BBB+ATM+ATM RNC+ATM NodeB+DCN NodeB)")) {
                         currentStatus = jh.callExcelMacroOtEnchaine(newRecordingPath, csvPath.replace("/", "\\") + "\\", selectedRegion, file, equivalentOT, obj, isChechBoxGSMValue(), isChechBoxDCSValue(), isChechBoxU900Value(), isChechBoxUMTSValue(), userName + "." + userFirstName + "\\" + genFolder, selectedTechnology);
                    } else {
                          currentStatus = jh.callExcelMacro(newRecordingPath, csvPath.replace("/", "\\") + "\\", selectedRegion, file, equivalentOT, obj, isChechBoxGSMValue(), isChechBoxDCSValue(), isChechBoxU900Value(), isChechBoxUMTSValue(), userName + "." + userFirstName + "\\" + genFolder);
                    }
                    generatedSites.add(new GeneratedSiteStatus(currentSite, currentStatus));
                         context.update("genDialog");
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":blockA:initGenPan:sitesDataList");
                }
}`
```

I would to display the list  generatedSites when it is changed in this Dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="genDialog" header="Opération de génération" closable="false" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg1">
        <h:form id="dialogForm">
            <p:panel style="border-spacing: 0px;" >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:outputText value="le traitement de la génération est en cours..." />
                    <p:dataList id="sitesDataList" value="#{generationBean.generatedSites}" var="siteStatus" itemType="square" >
                        #{siteStatus.site} #{' '}------------- #{' '}#{siteStatus.status}
                    </p:dataList>
                    <!--<p:poll global="false" update="sitesDataList"/>-->

                    <p:commandButton value="Valider" actionListener="#{generationBean.updateGeneratedSites()}"  style=" font: -moz-button; left: 90px; width: 90px;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
```

I'm using primefaces 3.5 with JSF2 and i'm running in glassfish3.0.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Show the backingbean code as well as  xhtml.

Comment: `<p:dialogBox>` doesn't exist. What are you talking about? Some concrete code in SSCCE flavor would help so much in actually understanding what you're trying to achieve instead of such a poor formulation.

Comment: @BalusC i'm sorry for this mistakes. I'm confusing dialogBox on VBA and p:dialog of primefaces.